# Boost::bind 'Call to empty boost::function' fails only if not set in constructor

Tags: c++, boost

Why might using the following fail unless called from the constructor of the class?

```
    updateState = boost::bind( &PhysicsObject::updateActive, this );
```

However the following fails at runtime, with a 'what():  call to empty boost::function' exception

```
void PhysicsObject::setState( PhsyicsObjectState aState ) {
_state = aState;

if( _state == ACTIVE ) { // This branch is executed
    updateState = boost::bind( &PhysicsObject::updateActive, this );
} else {
    updateState = boost::bind( &PhysicsObject::updateExploding, *this );
}
}
```

Comment: That `*this` in the second `bind` call looks suspicious

Comment: You're right, i only set it that way when I went into - let me try this or that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling a `boost::function` that wasn't set would raise such exception. You should initialize it in your constructor according to the default "state", otherwise your `setState` won't set it if passed a state same as the current.

Note that in your second bind, you are passing a **copy** of the object pointed by `this`.

Comment: That never happens, i updated the code and question to reflect that. Sorry for the confusion.