# Access protocol buffers extension fields

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, protocol-buffers

I am working with protocol buffers in C++. My message has only one extension range. And I want to access all the extension fields without knowing their name, using only their numbers. How can I do this??

```
message Base {
    optional int32 id = 1;
    extensions 1000 to 1999;     
}

extend Base{
    optional int32 id2 = 1000;
}
```

Up till now, I have obtained ExtensionRange.

```
const google::protobuf::Descriptor::ExtensionRange* rng = desc->extension_range(0);
std::cerr << "rng " << rng->start << " " << rng->end << std::endl;
```

But I donot know to to get the `Fielddescriptor*` of the extensions.

There is one weird thing and that is `extension_count()` is returning 0.   Although I have used extension in my .proto file. Similarly FindExtensionBy[Name/number] are not working as expected?

Comment: check boost::function that you are using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870600/boostbind-call-to-empty-boostfunction-fails-only-if-not-set-in-constructor

Comment: @PiotrNycz, I changed the problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using reflection.

```
const Reflection* ref = message_.GetReflection(); 
const FieldDescriptor* cfield = ref->FindKnownExtensionByNumber(33);

std::cerr << "cfield->name() " << cfield->name() << std::endl;
```

Now my existing solution will be to loop for all the numbers in extension range and get the required Fielddescriptors of the extensions.

I am still waiting for any better/different solution, you guys.

Comment: Note that the above code is `using namespace google::protobuf`

Answer (score -1):

To cite from the official `descriptor.h` documentation:

> To get a FieldDescriptor for an extension, do one of the following:
>
> - Get the Descriptor or FileDescriptor for its containing scope, then
>     call Descriptor::FindExtensionByName() or
>     FileDescriptor::FindExtensionByName().
> - Given a DescriptorPool, call
>     DescriptorPool::FindExtensionByNumber().
> - Given a Reflection for a
>     message object, call Reflection::FindKnownExtensionByName() or
>     Reflection::FindKnownExtensionByNumber(). Use DescriptorPool to
>     construct your own descriptors.

The reason why `extension_count()` is returning 0 is that it tells you the number of nested extension *declarations* (for other message types).